# Suspicious warning about a Kernel Extension

Tags: macos, software-update, malware, kernel-extensions

This morning i received this warning from BlockBlock about a new kernel extension being installed. I'm running OS X 10.11.4.

[image]
I looked up on google and found out that it could be related to a blacklisted ethernet driver. I decided to allow but then i turned off the machine. Could this be some malware or it just an update from Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your machine (i.e. what OS are you on?  possibly not El Capitan (OS 10.11.x), but that's an educated guess...) it is difficult to say, BUT Apple would update your computer through the Apple Store, and it would not just dump a Kernel Extension like that.  About your Kext there, I would not have a clue, but a quick google does not come up with [exctitingly good news](https://medium.com/@sabrihaddouche/automatic-updates-of-kernel-extensions-in-os-x-9b75b3e45c97#.uxw5p1oer).  I trust you have a backup of your data.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm on 10.11.4 The article you posted the exact same scenario, in fact i also remember some softwareupdated activity. So, do you think it's safe?

Comment: I mean, the fact that the update (should) come from Apple is a bit reassuring, however, inside that kext i see a lot of blacklisted kexts from security software like sophos little snitch, hands off, karspersky, maybe they blocked older versions.

Comment: Did you disable the System Integrity Protection?  Assuming you have NOT is should stop the installation of unsigned Kexts.  Which does not mean that trusted certificates cannot be stolen and malware pushed on that way...

Comment: I kept it enabled. By the way, I've just found put that it shouldn't be malicious: https://twitter.com/objective_see/status/717491496971153409